# Ubuntu Cloud image 14.04 (Trusty Tahr) only has one network interface (eth0)

Tags: 14.04, server, kvm-virtualization, cloud, cloud-init

i'm really new in the cloud world so i need some help because after several day surfing the internet i didn't find anything..

I launch a VM with kvm using this image:
[cloud-images.ubuntu.com/server/releases/14.04/release/ubuntu-14.04-server-cloudimg-amd64-disk1.img/ubuntu-14.04-server-cloudimg-amd64-disk1.img](http://cloud-images.ubuntu.com/server/releases/14.04/release/ubuntu-14.04-server-cloudimg-amd64-disk1.img/ubuntu-14.04-server-cloudimg-amd64-disk1.img) .

After i passing the password with cloud-utils file i can login into the new VM but only has one network interface, anyone know other image with two interfaces i can use?? because i need to have 2 interfaces eth0 for my project.

On the internet i found maybe in this path /etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rule i can find my local network rules to name your network cards, but in my case i checked the path and i don't have the file "70-persistent-net.rules"

some ideas what can i do? o what image i can use? or maybe other way to solve my problem??

Thanks

Ivan

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you are better of installing [virtualbox](http://virtualbox.org). It has a nice user interface and good documentation to help you with configurations like ethernet interfaces. And you can just any image for booting (also your favorite Ubuntu image). At least *I* am an enthusiastic user. Perhaps you can than later progress to kvm and the likes.

---

*Side note*: You might also want to try out [vagrant](http://vagrantup.com) in combination with [ansible](http://ansible.com) to manage and configure headless machines - very powerful

Comment: thanks, i wil check vagrant and ansible, but i can't use virtualbox because i have a dedicated server and as far i know to virtual box i need and OS with GUI. Also the work i have to do is with kvm...

Comment: still might be useful to set it up with virtualbox on your desktop, because it can configure multiple interfaces, and than peek how it does it with ubuntu. The way network devices are set up is quite distribution specific. [headless virtualbox](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=38323) *is* possible.